# Protractor - get text of a child element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I'm using Protractor to test an angular page. This page has a table populated by ng-repeat and I would like to extra the text within that table. Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="data-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="group in tableData  | filter: filterText | orderBy: getValueToOrderByGroup() : sortingCriteria.descending" ng-show="filtered.length > 0">
<div class="data-row group-header">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <i ng-click="group.hideRows = !group.hideRows" ng-class="{'rotate-down': group.hideRows}" class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-right"></i>
        <strong class="text-capitalize ng-binding" ng-click="group.hideRows = !group.hideRows"> HEADER TEXT </strong>
    </div>
</div>

<div collapse="group.hideRows" class="collapse in" style="height: auto;">

    <div class="data-row child-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="thing in filtered = (group.data | filter: filterStuff | filter: filterText | orderBy: getValueToOrderByChild() : sortingCriteria.descending)">

        <div class="col-md-3 cell-data child-row-indent text-capitalize">
            <span class="clickable-element ng-binding">CHILD ONE</span>&nbsp;<br>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-2 child-row-indent-responsive">
            <span class="visible-xs visible-sm">Status:&nbsp;</span><span class="ng-binding"> CHILD TWO </span>
        </div>           
    </div>
</div>
```

And these are my statements to extract the text:

```
var headerText = element.all(by.repeater('group in tableData')).get(0).all(by.tagName('div')).get(0).element(by.css('div > strong')).getText();

var childOne = element.all(by.repeater('group in tableData')).get(0).all(by.tagName('div')).get(1).element(by.css('div > div:nth-child(1) > span').getText();
```

When I ran this, it returned a whole block of all the functions but not the actual text. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to understand that `WebdriverJS` and `protractor` itself are entirely based on the concept of promises due to their asynchronous nature. See [Promises and the Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md#promises-and-the-control-flow).

In other words, `getText()` in your case **returns a promise**. If you want to see the actual value, you need to resolve it:

```
headerText.then(function (text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Note that you don't need to resolve promises inside an `expect()` - it knows how to resolve promises before making an expectation (thanks to [`jasminewd`](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd)).